# COMSOL modelling wicking of paper in 3D

Tags: finite-element-method

I am trying to model wicking of paper in 3D, by following the tutorial for paper wicking in 2D on the COMSOL Application Library , but ran into this error:

Undefined variable.

- Variable: phtr.pc_s2
- Geometry: geom1
- Boundary: 3
  Failed to evaluate Jacobian of expression.
- Expression: (comp1.p-comp1.dl.p0)*dvol
  Failed to evaluate Jacobian of expression.
- Expression: ((comp1.p-comp1.dl.p0)*test(-comp1.p_lm))*(dvol)

Attached is the file for everyone's reference.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

[Link to document](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsIaNiF_LTxFgTedrWEdyw_YXHIJ?e=un3OkN)